# How to refactor nested switch-case (Java) or when (Kotlin)?

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, functional-programming, stream

Requirement: I need code a Jo-Ken-Pô game which can be played with multiple players. There are 5 roles (SPOCK, scissors, paper, stone and lizard). I can accomplish it with these two chainned when/switches (the code bellow uses when() because it is in Kotlin but same idea can be applied using switch in Java)

```
  when (u1.play) {
        PlayType.SPOCK -> when (u2.play) {
            //SPOCK WINS
            PlayType.TESOURA -> return u1
            PlayType.PEDRA -> return u1
            //SPOCK LOSES
            PlayType.PAPEL -> return u2
            PlayType.LAGARTO -> return u2
        }
        PlayType.TESOURA -> when (u2.play) {
            //TESOURA (scissors) WINS
            PlayType.PAPEL -> return u1
            PlayType.LAGARTO -> return u1
            //TESOURA (scissors) LOSES
            PlayType.SPOCK -> return u2
            PlayType.PEDRA -> return u2
        }
        PlayType.PAPEL -> when (u2.play) {
            //PAPEL (paper) WINS
            PlayType.SPOCK -> return u1
            PlayType.PEDRA -> return u1
            //PAPEL (paper) LOSES
            PlayType.TESOURA -> return u2
            PlayType.LAGARTO -> return u2
        }
        PlayType.PEDRA -> when (u2.play) {
            //PEDRA (stone) WINS
            PlayType.LAGARTO -> return u1
            PlayType.TESOURA -> return u1
            //PEDRA (stone) LOSES
            PlayType.SPOCK -> return u2
            PlayType.PAPEL -> return u2
        }
        PlayType.LAGARTO -> when (u2.play) {
            //LAGARTO (lizard) WINS
            PlayType.SPOCK -> return u1
            PlayType.PAPEL -> return u1
            //LAGARTO (lizard) LOSES
            PlayType.TESOURA -> return u2
            PlayType.PEDRA -> return u2
        }
    }
```

I have read hours and hours trying to find how to turn this code more elegant using lambda but I can't find any clue. Please, any help will be very wellcome.

I will paste the whole code here. Although you see I am using lambda at least to call the method I am certainly missing some powerfull feature of lambda and almost coding as in Java 7< classical way.

All users come from a H2 database. Here are the repository

```
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.model.User
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Long>
```

User model

```
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.enums.PlayType
import javax.persistence.*


@Entity
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        val name: String,

        @Enumerated
        @Column(nullable = false)
        val play: PlayType

)
```

Enum PlayType

```
enum class PlayType(val value: Int) {
    SPOCK(1), TESOURA(2), LAGARTO(3), PAPEL(4), PEDRA(5)
}
```

The Service *** HERE ARE THE ISSUES ***

```
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.enums.PlayType
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.model.User
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.respository.UserRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class GameService(private val userRepository: UserRepository) {

    fun returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(u1: User, u2: User): User {

        when (u1.play) {
            PlayType.SPOCK -> when (u2.play) {
                //SPOCK WINS
                PlayType.TESOURA -> return u1
                PlayType.PEDRA -> return u1
                //SPOCK LOSES
                PlayType.PAPEL -> return u2
                PlayType.LAGARTO -> return u2
            }
            PlayType.TESOURA -> when (u2.play) {
                //TESOURA (scissors) WINS
                PlayType.PAPEL -> return u1
                PlayType.LAGARTO -> return u1
                //TESOURA (scissors) LOSES
                PlayType.SPOCK -> return u2
                PlayType.PEDRA -> return u2
            }
            PlayType.PAPEL -> when (u2.play) {
                //PAPEL (paper) WINS
                PlayType.SPOCK -> return u1
                PlayType.PEDRA -> return u1
                //PAPEL (paper) LOSES
                PlayType.TESOURA -> return u2
                PlayType.LAGARTO -> return u2
            }
            PlayType.PEDRA -> when (u2.play) {
                //PEDRA (stone) WINS
                PlayType.LAGARTO -> return u1
                PlayType.TESOURA -> return u1
                //PEDRA (stone) LOSES
                PlayType.SPOCK -> return u2
                PlayType.PAPEL -> return u2
            }
            PlayType.LAGARTO -> when (u2.play) {
                //LAGARTO (lizard) WINS
                PlayType.SPOCK -> return u1
                PlayType.PAPEL -> return u1
                //LAGARTO (lizard) LOSES
                PlayType.TESOURA -> return u2
                PlayType.PEDRA -> return u2
            }
        }
        return u1
    }

    fun playGameWithAll(): User? {
        val allUsers = userRepository.findAll().toList()

        val winner = allUsers.reduce { a, b ->
            returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(a, b)
        }

        if (allUsers.filter { player -> player.play == winner.play }
                        .count() == 1)
            return winner
        else
            return null

    }
}
```

The code above works as expected but I have the filling I am bad coding for two reasons:

1 - I split two small lambda statement: reduce to compare each other playtype and just to figure if there  are more than one winner I coded .count separated

2 - certainly there might be a more elegant and readble way to code two chainned switches with lambda but I can get even the first step to try

PS: the code is Kotlin but if you point anything in Java I can easily translate it to kotlin. Any trick or suggestion how refactory will be highly appreciated

Anyone interested to get the game fill free to clone from https://github.com/jimisdrpc/games.git

*** edited after Mikhail's answer

Main.java

```
    package poc;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Optional;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Fake returned list from database
            List<User> usersList = List.of(
                    new User(1L, "Jimis", PlayType.LAGARTO),
                    new User(2L, "Drpc", PlayType.PAPEL));


            //User winnerUser = returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(usersList.get(0), usersList.get(1));

            Optional<User> winnerUser  = usersList.stream().reduce( (a, b) ->
            returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(a , b));

            System.out.print(winnerUser);

        }

        //Trying to refactoring from classical switch to some structure for using with lambda
        private final static Map<PlayType, Set<PlayType>> CONFIG = Map.of(
                PlayType.SPOCK,
                    Set.of(PlayType.TESOURA, PlayType.PEDRA), 
                PlayType.TESOURA, 
                    Set.of(PlayType.PAPEL, PlayType.LAGARTO)

        );

        private static User returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(User u1, User u2) {
/// ****** Exception next line
            if (CONFIG.get(u1.getPlay()).contains(u2.getPlay())) {
                return u1;
            }
            return u2;
        }
    }
```

User model

```
package poc;

public class User {

    Long id;
    String name;
    PlayType play;

    public User(Long id, String name, PlayType play) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.play = play;
    }

//... getters/setters removed
}
```

PlayType enum

```
package poc;

public enum PlayType {
    SPOCK,
    TESOURA, 
    PEDRA, 
    PAPEL,
    LAGARTO;
}
```

Exception when running this part CONFIG.get(u1.getPlay()).contains(u2.getPlay()

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at moduleinfo/poc.Main.returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(Main.java:39)
    at moduleinfo/poc.Main.lambda$0(Main.java:21)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$2ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:558)
    at moduleinfo/poc.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

If I try simplify and call without stream().reduce() I get this issue in same point

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at moduleinfo/poc.Main.returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(Main.java:49)
    at moduleinfo/poc.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

*** final solution

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Fake returned list from database
        List<User> usersList = List.of(
                new User(1L, "Jogador 1", PlayType.PEDRA),
                new User(2L, "Jogador 2", PlayType.TESOURA),
                new User(3L, "Jogador 3", PlayType.TESOURA),
                new User(4L, "Jogador 4", PlayType.SPOCK)
                );


        Optional<User> winnerUser  = usersList.stream().reduce( (a, b) ->
            returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(a , b));

        System.out.print(winnerUser.get().getName());

    }

    private final static Map<PlayType, Set<PlayType>> CONFIG = Map.of(
            PlayType.SPOCK,
                Set.of(PlayType.TESOURA, PlayType.PEDRA), 
            PlayType.TESOURA, 
                Set.of(PlayType.PAPEL, PlayType.LAGARTO),
            PlayType.PAPEL, 
                Set.of(PlayType.SPOCK, PlayType.PEDRA),
            PlayType.PEDRA, 
                Set.of(PlayType.LAGARTO, PlayType.TESOURA),
            PlayType.LAGARTO, 
                Set.of(PlayType.SPOCK, PlayType.PAPEL)
    );

    private static User returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(User u1, User u2) {
        if (CONFIG.get(u1.getPlay()).contains(u2.getPlay())) {
            return u1;
        }
        return u2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is a good example on the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898): You are thinking/asking about **how** to solve a problem, having a technical solution (lambdas) already in mind. Insetad you ought to think/ask about **what** you are trying to achieve: readable code without unnecessary duplication in content and structure. Which is why maybe you want to think about representing the game rules as a good, old-fashioned, multi-dimensional array or maybe as a map of sets as Mikhail suggested, if you want it more fancy.

Comment: @kriegaex, thanks for commenting. I understood yo are giving me some warnning how to improve my question. What do you think could be improve? As you said "Insetad you ought to think/ask about what you are trying to achieve: readable code without unnecessary duplication in content and structure." do you recommend me to edit the question title with "readable code without unnecessary duplication in content and structure". BTW, I just read the "XY problem" answer you mentioned and I can add any extra information desired.

Comment: How do you like the question title after I changed it? It is more concrete at the one hand and also less fixated on a technical solution on the other hand. I did not rephrase your question as such, though.

Comment: @kriegaex, thanks. Much better! I will use your suggestion to improve my next questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `switch inside switch` construction looks really hard to read, you're right.

Think of it this way: each PlayType wins from some others. And this information look like a configuration, so can be described in a declarative way, like this:

- SPOCK wins against TESOURA & PEDRA
- TESOURA wins against PAPEL & LAGARTO
- etc

So you can just define a `Map<PlayType, Set<PlayType>>` and verify if `u2.play is contained by map.get(u1.play)`

UPD. Code example (java, written in notepad, so may contain some syntax mistakes)

```java
class GameService {
  private final static Map<PlayType, Set<PlayType>> CONFIG = Map.of(
    PlayType.SPOCK, Set.of(PlayType.TESOURA, PlayType.PEDRA),
    PlayType.TESOURA, Set.of(PlayType.PAPEL, PlayType.LAGARTO)
    //etc
  );

  function User returnWinnerBetweenTwoPlayers(User u1, User u2){
    if (CONFIG.get(u1.getType()).contains(u2.getType()){
      return u1;
    }
    return u2;
  } 
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I can see you have a much better approach in you mind but I didn't get your point. Kindly, can you extend your answer exemplifying it? Maybe it is obvious for someone very experient with Lambda but I didn't understand how "define a Map<PlayType, Set<PlayType>> and verify if u2.play is contained by map.get(u1.play)" can apply to my case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunatelly either I didn't understand your suggestion or something is wrong in your purposal. I added above in Java the resulted tentative. I removed all extra code unnecessary for this discussion and foced only your suggestion with edition above

Comment: Yep, sure - you have more PlayType options  than I described in the example. Only SPOCK and TESOURA are described while you are checking LAGARTO and PAPEL. Just add the latter two to the map (instead of `//etc` in my example) and you're done